# Yii Валидация модели

Tags: yii

Здраствуйте. Есть правило валидации

```
 array('email', 'unique', 'message'=>'This email already exists','on' => 'register').
```

Проблема в том что другие при возникновении ошибок в других валидаторах (`required,compare` и т.д), сообщение во view на екран выводится, но при `unique` нет реакции. Подскажите,как правильно задать вывод даной ошибки в случае возникновения? Спасибо.

```
$this->pageTitle = Yii::app()->name . ' - Registration';
?>

<div class="form">
    <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'login-form',
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'clientOptions' => array(
            'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        ),
    )); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'username'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'email'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'password'); ?>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'passwordConfirm'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'passwordConfirm'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'passwordConfirm'); ?>

    </div>


    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Registration'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Дополните вопрос пожалуйста. Покажите код вьюшки. И чего именно вы хотите? Динамической валидации через ajax? Или обычной серверной валидации?

Comment: Мне просто надо чтобы при совпадении емейла что вводится в форме с емейлом из базы выводилось соответственное сообщение что  такой емейл уже есть. С аяксом или без - без разницы

Comment: Вы программист, Вам решать как будет, не может быть без разницы! Или узнайте у заказчика.

Comment: Имею в виду что это несущественно,просто нужен нормальный вывод оишбки валидатора unique)

Comment: При этом запись с дублирующимся e-mail в базе появляется?